# Convert from multi stage build to single

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

As i'm limited to use docker 1.xxx instead of 17x on my cluster, I need some help on how to convert this multi stage build to a valid build for the older docker version.

Could someone help me?

```
FROM node:9-alpine as deps

ENV NODE_ENV=development

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm set progress=false  \
    && npm config set depth 0 \
    && npm install --only=production \
    && cp -R node_modules/ ./prod_node_modules \
    && npm install

FROM deps as test

RUN rm -r ./prod_node_modules \
  && npm run lint

FROM node:9-alpine
RUN apk add --update tzdata

ENV PORT=3000
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=deps /app .
COPY --from=deps /app/prod_node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Currently it gives me error on "FROM node:9-alpine as deps"

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with Docker? It seems like you're just copying and pasting stuff without really understanding what's going on (based on this and your other question). I'd read up a bit on https://docs.docker.com/v17.03/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/ and https://blog.alexellis.io/mutli-stage-docker-builds/ (specifically the first part on the builder pattern as you can't do multi-stage builds with your version).

Answer (score 5):

"`FROM node:9-alpine as deps`" means you are defining an intermediate image that you will be able to `COPY` from `COPY --from=deps`.

Having a single image means you don't need to `COPY --from` anymore, and you don't need "`as deps`" since everything happens in the same image (which will be bigger as a result)

So:

```
FROM node:9-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=development

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm set progress=false  \
    && npm config set depth 0 \
    && npm install --only=production \
    && cp -R node_modules/ ./prod_node_modules \
    && npm install

RUN rm -r ./prod_node_modules \
  && npm run lint

RUN apk add --update tzdata

ENV PORT=3000
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /root/
RUN cp -r /app .
RUN cp -r /app/prod_node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Only *one* `FROM` here.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Getting error : Step 12/15 : COPY /app .
lstat app: no such file or directory

Comment: Yes , it should not be COPY but RUN cp /app .

Comment: I really dont understand this.. I deleted the RUN rm -r ./prod_node_modules \
  && npm run lint & now it builds, but when running container it says can't find /root/index.js